# Compiler and linker flags in Rcpp: Magick++

Tags: c++, r, imagemagick, rcpp, magick++

I have an R script, which loads an Rcpp file. The Rcpp file needs the magick++ library, so I used:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <Magick++.h>
```

However when I run the script, I get:

```
fatal error: Magick++.h: No such file or directory
```

The library *libmagick++-dev* is installed.

How can I include Magick++ in an Rcpp file? How can I compile it with flags? For instance:

```
-DHAVE_CONFIG_H, -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16, -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0
```

A minimal working example:

**mwe.r**

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("./mwe.cpp")
```

**mwe.cpp**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <Magick++.h>
//[[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
```

Comment: Have you looked how [`magick`](https://github.com/ropensci/magick) incorporates it? You likely just need to set include and link paths, but you also haven't provided a MWE.

Comment: @hrbrmstr MWE included

Comment: You need to learn how to write a _package_ (as opposed to `source()`ing a file) which has an _external dependency_ in this case the Magick++ library.  Also note that just including a header file (as you did) is generally not sufficient ... unless the library is in fact header only.  Some are, and we use them because being header-only makes that easy. The normal case is with linking, and harder.  But many existing examples, and some documentation is available.

Comment: Did you install all of Imagemagick from binary with delegates or just the magick++ source?

Answer (score 4):

As @hrbrmstr mentions, there is a CRAN package [magick](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/index.html) that provides ImageMagick functionality already; maybe that avoids the need to do anything yourself?

From these [ImageMagick  instructions](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php) you can see that a C++ program needs to know about compiler flags (the output of `Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags`) and linker flags (`Magick++-config --ldflags --libs`).

The best way to compile Rcpp code with complicated compilation and linkage steps is (I'm no expert here...) to create an Rcpp package

```
/tmp$ Rdev --vanilla -e "Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton('Magick')"
/tmp$ cd Magick
```

I edited Magick/src/rcpp_hello_world.cpp to

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <Magick++.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalVector rcpp_hello_world()
{
    Magick::InitializeMagick("RcppMagick");
    return true;
}
```

And added package pre-processing, compilation, and linkage commands (following Writing R Extensions, available via `RShowDoc("R-exts")`) to a new file Magick/src/Makevars like

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = `Magick++-config --cppflags`
PKG_CXXFLAGS = `Magick++-config --cxxflags`
PKG_LIBS = `Magick++-config --ldflags --libs`
```

I then updated the attributes of my package, installed it, and verified that it could be used

```
/tmp/Magick master$ Rdev --vanilla -e "Rcpp::compileAttributes()"
> Rcpp::compileAttributes()
>
>
/tmp/Magick master$ Rdev --vanilla CMD INSTALL .
* installing to library ...‘/home/mtmorgan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5-Bioc-3.7’
* installing *source* package ‘Magick’ ...
** libs
g++  -I"/home/mtmorgan/bin/R-devel/include" -DNDEBUG `Magick++-config --cppflags` -I"/home/mtmorgan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5-Bioc-3.7/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include  `Magick++-config --cxxflags` -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++  -I"/home/mtmorgan/bin/R-devel/include" -DNDEBUG `Magick++-config --cppflags` -I"/home/mtmorgan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5-Bioc-3.7/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include  `Magick++-config --cxxflags` -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -c rcpp_hello_world.cpp -o rcpp_hello_world.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/local/lib -o Magick.so RcppExports.o rcpp_hello_world.o -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/X11 -lGraphicsMagick++ -lGraphicsMagick -ljbig -lwebp -llcms2 -ltiff -lfreetype -ljasper -ljpeg -lpng12 -lwmflite -lXext -lSM -lICE -lX11 -llzma -lbz2 -lxml2 -lz -lm -lgomp -lpthread
installing to /home/mtmorgan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5-Bioc-3.7/Magick/libs
...
/tmp/Magick master$ Rdev --vanilla -e "Magick::rcpp_hello_world()"
> Magick::rcpp_hello_world()
[1] TRUE
```

I had to figure out what system package to install to get Magick++-config. When I first tried to install my package R complained that it didn't know about `-lwebp`, so I installed that system dependency too (libwebp-dev). The package would be good enough for personal use, but would need to be more robust for cross-platform or production use. There could be many problems encountered while trying to integrate this complicated library into R.

Comment: Nice answer.  And once you are this far, and care enough, it is easy to ready up creation of a "plugin" in the Rcpp Attribution parlance so that these flags can be used by referring to the plugin from the package, and getting the flags from it.  RcppGSL is an example, as is RcppMLPACK.